# ParseJSON Error for HTTPPost - SSJS Unable to retrieve security descriptor

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, json, ssjs, parser

In my marketing cloud, landing page.  Getting the error *`"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame"`* while trying to Parse the JSON response in a HTTP Post call.

The response is received perfectly in *`respContent`* shown below. The response has `shortLink` - unable to parse it to extract the `shortLink`. The issue is with `Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response);`

I did try other solutions provided on SFSE but didn't work too.

**Code**

```
var url = 'xxxxxx';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var payload = '{"longDynamicLink": "https://xxxxx/?link='+encoded';
var headerNames = ["name"];
var headerValues = ["application/json"];
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response);

Write("<br/>respContent :" + result.Response +"<br/>");
Write("<br/>shortLink :" + content.shortLink+"<br/>");
```

**Output**

```
respContent :{ "shortLink": "https://xxx.link/89eQ",
 "previewLink": "https://xxx.link/89eQ?d=1" }

    The error is :{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.",
"description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the fix.

Had to use [0] for the response.

```
var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
```